# How to insert a date into a DATETIME column?

Tags: php

How can I insert a date into a `DATETIME` column (MySQL) in PHP?

I'm using PDO and I was just wondering. Should I use just date()?

But if I use `date()` I could give the column VARCHAR also.

So what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

using date data type helps in using in build procedures in SQL like sort
if u use a query like

```
select * from table ORDER BY DOB desc;
```

if your column data type is var char it will b sorted in alphabetical order and not the format u wanted but if the data type is date it will b sorted in terms of date and u dont need extra work to sort string to calendar-wise

Comment: thanks! so I could just use time() for inserting it?